# How come I can't use toLowerCase() after using a StringBuffer?

Tags: java, string

I read that in Java, String is immutable, so we can't really use toLowerCase intuitively, i.e the original string is unmodified:

```
String s = "ABC";
s.toLowerCase();

> "ABC"
```

But even using StringBuffer(which supports mutable Strings) does not work

```
StringBuffer so = new StringBuffer("PoP");

so.toLowerCase()

> Static Error: No method in StringBuffer has name 'toLowerCase'
```

I appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: `s = s.toLowerCase();`, `so.toString().toLowerCase()`...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, it doesn't. You'd have to use `.toString().toLowerCase()`:

```
String lowercase = sb.toString().toLowerCase();
```

If you want to be very strict about not creating unnecessary instances, you can iterate all characters, and lowercase them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
   char c = sb.charAt(i);
   sb.setCharAt(i, Character.toLowerCase(c));
}
```

And finally - prefer `StringBuilder` to `StringBuffer`

Comment: Which, just to clarify for Adel, will still not modify your StringBuffer. It'll return a new String with the contents in lowercase. So you would do something like `String s = so.toString().toLowerCase();`

Comment: Thanks so much. I just did `so.toString().toLowerCase()` and it did change it... though the original so variable still is "PoP" , so I'm a little confused what's the advantage of StringBuffer ?

Answer (score 1):

This function is about 20% faster than using "String lowercase = sb.toString().toLowerCase();" :

```
public static StringBuilder StringBuilderLowerCase(StringBuilder pText) {
        StringBuilder pTextLower = new StringBuilder(pText);
        for (int idx = 0; idx < pText.length(); idx++) {
            char c = pText.charAt(idx);
            if (c >= 65 && c <= 65 + 27) {
                pTextLower.setCharAt(idx, (char) ((int) (pText.charAt(idx)) | 32));
            }
        }
        return pTextLower;
}
```

Comment: Not using StringBuilder but rather char[] is even faster, about 75% faster.